# Can't open Xcode 6.4 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macos, xcode, crash

I keep my mac os x updated but this seems to have corrupted Xcode. When I try to run the terminal command:
`$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`
I get the following error...any clues?

objc[9160]: Class IDEBlockScrollView is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEProductsUI.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEProductsUI. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

2015-09-10 16:39:03.035 Xcode[9160:334069] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources."  (dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration): Library not loaded:  /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/Versions/A/MediaAccessibility
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/Versions/A/AVKit
  Reason: image not found) UserInfo=0x7fa56cad3230  {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/Versions/A/MediaAccessibility
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/Versions/A/AVKit
  Reason: image not found, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, 0): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/Versions/A/MediaAccessibility
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/Versions/A/AVKit
  Reason: image not found
2015-09-10 16:39:03.038 Xcode[9160:334069] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension Xcode.InterfaceBuilderKit.CocoaTouchIntegration.Singletons: Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo=0x7fa569f42750 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, 0): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/Versions/A/MediaAccessibility
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/Versions/A/AVKit
  Reason: image not found, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa56ca7a960 "The bundle “IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources."}
2015-09-10 16:39:03.044 Xcode[9160:334069] [MT] DVTAssertions: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for parameter key 'name' of extension 'Xcode.InterfaceBuilderKit.CocoaTouchIntegration.Singletons' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration'
UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x7fa569f42750 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration, 0): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/Versions/A/MediaAccessibility\n  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/Versions/A/AVKit\n  Reason: image not found, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa56ca7a960 \"The bundle \U201cIDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
}
Hints: None
2015-09-10 16:39:03.132 Xcode[9160:334069] [MT] DVTAssertions: 
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff9072f024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x0000000104908c34 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff8e35776e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x000000010476a5c4 -[DVTExtensionParameter valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010f5d53f1 -[IBScopedSingletonRegistry init] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000010f5d5148 __43+[IBScopedSingletonRegistry sharedInstance]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x00007fff9041ec13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff9041eb26 dispatch_once_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x000000010f5d511d +[IBScopedSingletonRegistry sharedInstance] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x000000010f1ba9c5 -[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin init] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10  0x000000010f1ba912 +[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x000000010538df0f _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
 12  0x000000010538d79d _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
 13  0x000000010538d277 __IDEInitialize_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 14  0x000000010538d9c5 IDESetSafeToLoadMobileDevice (in IDEFoundation)
 15  0x000000010597400c -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x0000000105973ead -[IDEWelcomeWindowController openWelcomeWindowAfterFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate:] (in IDEKit)
 17  0x0000000105973be1 -[IDEApplicationController applicationOpenUntitledFile:] (in IDEKit)
 18  0x00007fff92fbd0fa -[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled] (in AppKit)
 19  0x00007fff92fbcb81 __58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 20  0x00007fff932660f0 __95-[NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateRegisteringAsReadyWhenDone:completionHandler:]_block_invoke557 (in AppKit)
 21  0x00007fff92fbc949 __97-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 (in AppKit)
 22  0x00007fff92fbc491 -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 23  0x00007fff93266034 -[NSPersistentUIRestorer finishedRestoringWindowsWithZOrder:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff93264d6c -[NSPersistentUIRestorer restoreStateFromRecords:usingDelegate:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff932644a1 -[NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateRegisteringAsReadyWhenDone:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 26  0x00007fff92fbac07 -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x00007fff92fba939 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff92fba385 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] (in AppKit)
 29  0x00007fff91d24818 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in Foundation)
 30  0x0000000105bb6f34 -[NSAppleEventManager(DVTAssertionOverrides) swizzleDispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in IDEKit)
 31  0x00007fff91d24689 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler (in Foundation)
 32  0x00007fff92beb43c aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) (in AE)
 33  0x00007fff92beb1b9 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) (in AE)
 34  0x00007fff92beb0c3 aeProcessAppleEvent (in AE)
 35  0x00007fff89230c6e AEProcessAppleEvent (in HIToolbox)
 36  0x00007fff92fb3da2 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 37  0x00007fff92fb2e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 38  0x0000000104e8daaa -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 39  0x00007fff92fa8af3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 40  0x00007fff92f25244 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 41  0x00007fff85a835c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 42  0x0000000000000001
Abort trap: 6

Comment: Why don't you reinstalling the app ? it'll reinstall all of the missing contents

Comment: I uninstalled (deleted the Xcode.app for /Applications folder, then cleared the Trash) Xcode.app and installed the new Xcode 7 but now I still can't open up Xcode. But this time, I'm getting a difference error:
2015-09-16Xcode[53196:2093437] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.ideplugin), Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources."